# I have spent the last 8 hours trying to pass a simple JSON object with some data from an api through my express backend to one of my react components

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, database, express

The initial goal was to get data from the API im using on the backend, add that data into my database, then res.json the data so it can be grabbed from the front end via fetch. Every single way that I have tried to pass down the data through props on components in react, I tried putting the logic to fetch the backend data right inside the component I need it, I've tried mapping the article objects returned by the api into arrays, I even tried pushing keys and values from the objects into a separate array. Please help me. I also tried passing down the json as props through the homepage, down to the story tile, but no matter what my data always seemed to be undefined or it even gave me an array of only 19 numbers at one point. I don't know what's going on, it seems so simple but I just cant figure it out. Also, if you see anything I can do to improve my code itself, or the process of writing it, feel free to tell me as I am still learning.

**home.js backend written in express**

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const ExpressError = require("../ExpressError");
const axios = require("axios");
const db = require("../db");
const async = require("async");

router.get("/headlines", async function (req, res, next) {
  try {
    let response = await axios.get(
      "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=f8d82ce36f72429fa0101925988eccee"
    );
    let resp = response.data.articles;
    for (let i in resp) {
      let title = resp[i].title;
      let name = resp[i].source.name;
      let img = resp[i].urlToImage;
      let description = resp[i].description;
      let url = resp[i].url;
      let content = resp[i].content;
      let author = resp[i].author;
      await db.query(
        `INSERT INTO home_articles (title, company_name, img, description, original_url, content, author) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7)`,
        [title, name, img, description, url, content, author]
      );
    }
    let dbInfo = await db.query(`SELECT * FROM home_articles LIMIT 10`);
    res.send(dbInfo.rows);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
});
module.exports = router;
```

**React App**

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import HomePage from "./HomePage";
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <HomePage></HomePage>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Home Page Child of App**

```
import React from "react";
import StoryTile from "./StoryTile";

function HomePage(props) {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <StoryTile></StoryTile>
    </div>
  );
}

export default HomePage;
```

**Story Tile Component and just a few of my failed attempts**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  Card,
  CardLink,
  CardText,
  CardBody,
  CardTitle,
  CardSubtitle,
} from "reactstrap";
import "./StoryTile.css";

const StoryTile = (props) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [isLoaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      await fetch("http://localhost:3001/headlines")
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => setData(data))
        .then(setLoaded(true));
    };
    getData();
  }, []);
  let articles = data.map((article) => [
    Object.keys(article),
    Object.values(article),
  ]);

  //   let article = [];
  //   for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  //     article.push(
  //       data.articles[i].title,
  //       data.articles[i].description,
  //       data.articles[i].urlToImage,
  //       data.articles[i].url,
  //       data.articles[i].content
  //     );
  //   }

  //   if (isLoaded) {
  //     for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  //       let title = data.title;
  //       articles.push(title);
  //     }
  //   }

  return (
    <div>
      <Card style={{ width: "18rem" }}>
        <CardBody>
          <CardTitle tag="h5">{articles}</CardTitle>
          <CardSubtitle tag="h6" className="mb-2 text-muted">
            Card subtitle
          </CardSubtitle>
        </CardBody>
        <img width="50%" alt="alt img" />
        <CardBody>
          <CardText>
            Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the
            bulk of the card's content.
          </CardText>
          <CardLink href="#">Card Link</CardLink>
          <CardLink href="#">Another Link</CardLink>
        </CardBody>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
};

export default StoryTile;
```

The data I send from the backend is an array that looks like this:

```
[
   {
      "article_id":1,
      "title":"2021 Ryder Cup results, scores, standings: United States continues dominance with largest lead since 1975 - CBSSports.com",
      "company_name":"CBS Sports",
      "img":"https://sportshub.cbsistatic.com/i/r/2021/09/25/f83b3816-2f68-4568-bedb-1fdbe76cf264/thumbnail/1200x675/f7f6db64dead459eff2aee5eb6776d8a/dustin-johnson.jpg",
      "description":"The Americans have run up and down the leaderboard on the Europeans through two days",
      "original_url":"https://www.cbssports.com/golf/news/2021-ryder-cup-results-scores-standings-united-states-continues-dominance-with-largest-lead-since-1975/live/",
      "content":"The second day of the Ryder Cup is in the rearview with the United States picking up where it left off Friday, grabbing five points between the morning and afternoon sessions and extending its lead t… [+5358 chars]",
      "author":"Kyle Boone"
   },
   {
      "article_id":2,
      "title":"NC State knocks off No. 9 Clemson in overtime - WRALSportsFan.com",
      "company_name":"WRALSportsFan.com",
      "img":"https://wwwcache.wralsportsfan.com/asset/football/college_football/2021/09/23/19890920/media_7802b2d78d4d4e919ab13d9e81367cf2-DMID1-5sc3obwic-640x480.jpg",
      "description":"NC State picked up its first win over a top-10 team since 2012 on Saturday with a 27-21 upset of No. 9 Clemson in double overtime.",
      "original_url":"https://www.wralsportsfan.com/nc-state-knocks-off-no-9-clemson-in-overtime/19894989/",
      "content":"By Joe Giglio, WRALSportsFan\r\nNC States losing streak to Clemson is history, so is the Tigers College Football Playoff streak.\r\nDevin Carters 22-yard touchdown catch gave the Wolfpack a 27-21 overtim… [+2436 chars]",
      "author":"Joe Giglio"
   },
   {
      "article_id":3,
      "title":"Meghan Markle Wore a Chic White Valentino Mini Dress to the Global Citizen Live Concert - Yahoo Lifestyle",
      "company_name":"ELLE.com",
      "img":"https://s.yimg.com/ny/api/res/1.2/vpBbcBBmlkD8MyE0iRd_RQ--/YXBwaWQ9aGlnaGxhbmRlcjt3PTEyMDA7aD02MDE-/https://s.yimg.com/uu/api/res/1.2/TF0lf11lvTbsZ6OEAF5Y5Q--~B/aD0xNDQwO3c9Mjg3NTthcHBpZD15dGFjaHlvbg--/https://media.zenfs.com/en/elle_570/0b93aec5300eb575d3456e9fa562bfcc",
      "description":"The Duke and Duchess of Sussex spoke about COVID vaccine equity during the concert.",
      "original_url":"https://www.elle.com/culture/celebrities/a37736968/meghan-markle-white-mini-dress-global-citizen-live-concert/",
      "content":"Meghan Markle and Prince Harry's biggest public appearance yet this fall, the Global Citizen Live concert, came and went this Saturday afternoon. The couple appeared during the Central Park event to … [+1487 chars]",
      "author":"Alyssa Bailey"
   },
   {
      "article_id":4,
      "title":"Dog the Bounty Hunter shows up at Brian Laundrie’s family home in North Port, knocks on door - WFLA",
      "company_name":"WFLA",
      "img":"https://www.wfla.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/71/2021/09/DOG-BOUNTY-HUNTER.jpg?w=1280",
      "description":"“Dog the Bounty Hunter” visited the family home of Brian Laundrie on Saturday afternoon.",
      "original_url":"https://www.wfla.com/news/sarasota-county/dog-the-bounty-hunter-shows-up-at-brian-laundries-family-home-in-north-port-knocks-on-door/",
      "content":"TAMPA, Fla. (WFLA) “Dog the Bounty Hunter” visited the family home of Brian Laundrie on Saturday afternoon.\r\nThe reality TV personality, whose real name is Duane Chapman, pulled up to the North Port … [+867 chars]",
      "author":"Athina Morris"
   },
   {
      "article_id":5,
      "title":"Nebraska billionaire, philanthropist Walter Scott dies at 90 - ABC News",
      "company_name":"ABC News",
      "img":"https://s.abcnews.com/images/US/WireAP_59be20711cdc4b7cbe1944e337004998_16x9_992.jpg",
      "description":"",
      "original_url":"https://abcnews.go.com/US/wireStory/nebraska-billionaire-philanthropist-walter-scott-dies-90-80235062",
      "content":"OMAHA, Neb. -- Billionaire Walter Scott, the past top executive of Peter Kiewit Sons Inc. construction firm who helped oversee Warren Buffetts conglomerate and donated to various causes, particularly… [+2504 chars]",
      "author":"JOSH FUNK Associated Press"
   },
   {
      "article_id":6,
      "title":"QB Jack Coan's injury doesn't appear serious; Brian Kelly sets Notre Dame mark for football coaching wins - ESPN",
      "company_name":"ESPN",
      "img":"https://a1.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=%2Fphoto%2F2021%2F0925%2Fr914162_1296x729_16%2D9.jpg",
      "description":"X-rays on Notre Dame's Jack Coan were \"clean,\" coach Brian Kelly said, after the quarterback left Saturday's win vs. Wisconsin. Kelly said he's \"pretty optimistic\" that Coan will play vs. No. 8 Cincinnati next week.",
      "original_url":"https://www.espn.com/college-football/story/_/id/32278978/qb-jack-coan-injury-appear-serious-brian-kelly-sets-notre-dame-mark-football-coaching-wins",
      "content":"CHICAGO -- Notre Dame coach Brian Kelly is \"pretty optimistic\" that quarterback Jack Coan won't miss next week's showdown against No. 8 Cincinnati after leaving Saturday's 41-13 victory against No. 1… [+3340 chars]",
      "author":"Adam Rittenberg"
   },
   {
      "article_id":7,
      "title":"UK warned visa plan to fix truck driver shortage will not solve crunch - Reuters UK",
      "company_name":"Reuters",
      "img":"https://www.reuters.com/resizer/sGOXojXEUuoqw5yaBgXn6A9gNxk=/1200x628/smart/filters:quality(80)/cloudfront-us-east-2.images.arcpublishing.com/reuters/O56VLV2HXJPWBL42ZAGIVLD2EA.jpg",
      "description":"Britain’s decision to issue temporary visas for 5,000 foreign truck drivers is a short-term fix that will not solve an acute labour shortage that risks major disruption for retailers in the run-up to Christmas, business leaders have warned.",
      "original_url":"https://www.reuters.com/world/uk/uk-warned-visa-plan-fix-truck-driver-shortage-will-not-solve-crunch-2021-09-25/",
      "content":"Lorries are seen at an HGV parking, at Cobham services on the M25 motorway, Cobham, Britain, August 31, 2021. REUTERS/Peter Cziborra/File PhotoLONDON, Sept 25 (Reuters) - Britains decision to issue t… [+3175 chars]",
      "author":null
   },
   {
      "article_id":8,
      "title":"Federal court temporarily blocks Covid-19 vaccine mandate for New York City teachers - CNN",
      "company_name":"CNN",
      "img":"https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/210925165929-elementary-school-bronx-new-york-08-17-2021-super-tease.jpg",
      "description":"A federal appeals court has issued a temporary injunction against a Covid-19 vaccine mandate for New York City educators set to go into effect early next week, temporarily blocking enforcement while the case is sent to a three-judge circuit court panel for re…",
      "original_url":"https://www.cnn.com/2021/09/25/us/new-york-city-teacher-vaccine-mandate-injunction/index.html",
      "content":null,
      "author":"Kristina Sgueglia and Dakin Andone, CNN"
   },
   {
      "article_id":9,
      "title":"Pelosi: Biden spending plan, infrastructure deal and funding ‘must pass’ next week - The Guardian",
      "company_name":"The Guardian",
      "img":null,
      "description":"Speaker sends letter to party at mercy of warring factions, prompting one reporter to observe: ‘Well, this is raising the stakes’",
      "original_url":"https://amp.theguardian.com/us-news/2021/sep/25/pelosi-biden-spending-plan-infrastructure-deal-government-funding-letter-democrats-republicans",
      "content":"Biden administration<ul><li>Speaker sends letter to party at mercy of warring factions</li><li>One reporter observes: Well, this is raising the stakes</li></ul>\r\nGuardian staff and agencies\r\nSat 25 S… [+5407 chars]",
      "author":"Guardian staff reporter"
   },
   {
      "article_id":10,
      "title":"La Palma volcano: Video captures collapse of volcanic cone, ash shuts down airport - Global News",
      "company_name":"Google News",
      "img":null,
      "description":null,
      "original_url":"https://news.google.com/__i/rss/rd/articles/CBMiK2h0dHBzOi8vd3d3LnlvdXR1YmUuY29tL3dhdGNoP3Y9VnJwNHQxYzdGLTTSAQA?oc=5",
      "content":null,
      "author":null
   }
]
```

**Devtools output**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'map')
    at StoryTile (StoryTile.js:25)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14985)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:17811)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19049)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23964)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22776)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22707)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:22670)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:22293)
    at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:21881)
    at updateContainer (react-dom.development.js:25482)
    at react-dom.development.js:26021
    at unbatchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:22431)
    at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (react-dom.development.js:26020)
    at Object.render (react-dom.development.js:26103)
    at Module.<anonymous> (index.js:7)
    at Module../src/index.js (index.js:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:856)
    at fn (bootstrap:150)
    at Object.1 (reportWebVitals.js:14)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:856)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32)
    at main.chunk.js:1
index.js:1 The above error occurred in the <StoryTile> component:

    at StoryTile (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:529:81)
    at div
    at HomePage (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:310:19)
    at div
    at App

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
console.<computed> @ index.js:1
react-dom.development.js:23275 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'map')
    at StoryTile (StoryTile.js:25)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14985)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:17811)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19049)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23964)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22776)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22707)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:22670)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:22293)
    at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:21881)
    at updateContainer (react-dom.development.js:25482)
    at react-dom.development.js:26021
    at unbatchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:22431)
    at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (react-dom.development.js:26020)
    at Object.render (react-dom.development.js:26103)
    at Module.<anonymous> (index.js:7)
    at Module../src/index.js (index.js:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:856)
    at fn (bootstrap:150)
    at Object.1 (reportWebVitals.js:14)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:856)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32)
    at main.chunk.js:1
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who's made it this far.

Comment: Did you try to print the data you get, to make sure it's the right form? Also notice you cannot simply render an object, you have to convert it into a component.

Comment: Trying to render the object in that Card Title was my way of seeing if I was getting the correct data, because for some reason anything that I console.log doesn't show up anywhere.

Comment: Looks like you are not getting the data in your frontend app. Openthe developer tools on your browser (F12 is a shortcut). If you see any errors in your console post them here. [ Could be proxy or cors issues ]

Comment: Also, refresh the page while on the Network tab to see all the requests made. Try to find the appropriate request to the backend and see if you get any statuses besides 200

Comment: I looked and it says that i got a 200 status code back from the backend, I'm also going to post what the dev tools errors are currently.

Comment: By the way, just a way to improve your code while we await your checks to be done, you can simplify the entire block from `let resp = response.data.articles;` to the closing bracket of the `for` loop to this: ```await Promise.all(response.data.articles.map(({ title, description, urlToImage: img, url, description, content, author, source: { name } }) => db.query(
        `INSERT INTO home_articles (title, company_name, img, description, original_url, content, author) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7)`, [title, name, img, description, url, content, author])));```

Comment: It says you have an error in the `StoryTitle` component where you're trying to call the property `map` of undefined.

Comment: This is because of my last attempt at taking all of the data from the objects and putting it into key val pair, seen after the useEffect in my StoryTitle.js, I know this is not correct but I had tried a lot of things at this point and think it was just a bad attempt,  it looks like this   let articles = data.map((article) => [
    Object.keys(article),
    Object.values(article),
  ]);

Comment: Well that means that `data` is undefined, which makes sense considering the initial value of the state is `null`. Place that code inside a useEffect that triggers only when data changes, and wrap it with a condition that makes sure `data` is truthy.

Comment: What would be the best way to map the Array of objects into a single array with key value pairs? Or some other way that allows me to dynamically use each individual articles title, content etc. and place that info onto its own card

Answer (score 3):

You haven't initialized your `data` state correctly. You're setting the default value to `null` and the first time the component renders `.map()` is called on `null` which causes the `TypeError`.

```js
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
```

And on a side note:

```
let articles = data.map((article) => [
    Object.keys(article),
    Object.values(article),
]);
```

Are you sure that's what you want? This will actually create an array of two arrays inside per each article:

```js
[
  [['author', 'title', ...all other properties], ['Christopher Mele', 'Amtrak Derailment: At Least 50 Hurt in Montana', ...all other values]],
  [['author', 'title', ...all other properties], [null, 'Amtrak Derailment: At Least 50 Hurt in Montana', ...all other values]],
  // and this for every article
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was one of my biggest problems for sure. It's the little things in coding that can throw the whole project off.

Comment: I actually had that exact thing rendering on my page, looks a lot messier when it's articles lol. What do you think would be the best way to store the values from the array of objects that my back end sends me, that would allow me to dynamically display title content, author etc. in my card components.

Comment: Just use them as they are returned from the back-end. No need to alter the objects' structure.